# How to sync data between offline and online in laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-4.2

I am developing a website where I need to sync data from offline to online and vice versa in Laravel 4.2. Can it be possible same as Whatsapp sync. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone has the answer or similar stackoverflow solved question, I have been waiting for more than 2 months and still not getting any response. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Laravel. Please use Vue.js to implement.

Comment: No, I am using Laravel 4.2. Vue.js not possible now.

Comment: Anyone has the answer or similar stackoverflow solved question, I have been waiting for more than 2 months and still not getting any response. Please help.